# How to get the calibration plot of a multivariable logistic regression model (glm)?

Tags: r, glm, calibration, rms

I have the following model and calculated the predicted probabilities:
 ( all variables are binary (0, 1) except AED_pre which is numeric (0:4)

```
modelfit <-glm(engelone ~ generalized + SEEG+ Aura + AED_pre + MS, data=data)
summary(modelfit)
prob <-predict(modelfit, type = c("response"))
```

I used SPSS to obtain the ROC curve, but I still need the calibration plots (+bootstrapping). I tried with:

```
val <- val.prob(data$prob, data$engelone, pl = TRUE)
```

but i get this error:

```
Error in qlogis(p) : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

What should i do? Thanks!

Here's my data :

```
structure(list(generalized = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), Aura = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), AED_pre = c(0, 
0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 4, 
5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 
2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
2, 6, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 
1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 3, 
2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 0, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 4, 0, 
3, 2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 
3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 
4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 
4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 
2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 
4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 0, 4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3
), SEEG = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), MS = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), engelone = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("generalized", 
"Aura", "AED_pre", "SEEG", "MS", "engelone"), row.names = c(NA, 
-316L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you please `dput()` your input data?

Comment: Just did- on the initial question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to see what variable class you have in your database, you can see it with class() and be sure you have numeric or factor variables. could try with this.

Comment: Thanks! I did it. All numeric :/


```
class(data$engelone)  
class(data$generalized)  
class(data$Aura)  
class(data$SEEG)
class(data$MS)
class(data$AED_pre)  

[1] "numeric"
[1] "numeric"
[1] "numeric"
[1] "numeric"
[1] "numeric"
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: I see something rare, because when I try it in R it turned to me an error that base$prob doesn't exists and it's true, you have to use val.prob(prob, data$engelone, pl = TRUE) instead of val.prob(data$prob, data$engelone, pl = TRUE) and when I run this he turned to me an error related with argumen 4 is NA, It would be because the val.prob() function needs some aditional arguments, you can see it in the examples if you put ?val.prob() like this val.prob(phat, y[101:200], m=20, cex=.5)  # subgroups of 20 obs. or this val.prob(phat, y[101:200], group=x1[101:200], g.group=2)